How can a polynomial term with a fractional coefficient have a GCF?
In my textbook, one of the questions presented was: find the greatest common factor for $\frac{5}{3}x^3$ and $\frac{4}{3}x$, and the answer listed in the back is $\frac{1}{3}x$.
In order to write $\frac{5}{3}x^3$ as a product of factors, you would have to write something like $5 \times x \times x \times x \times \frac{1}{3}$
The thing is though, if a fraction is an acceptable factor for a GCF, doesn't that sort of defeat the purpose of the GCF at all, because you could have an infinite amount of factors?
E.g. why is $2$ the GCF of $8$ and $6$, if I could just say $4 \times 2 = 8$ and $4 \times \frac{3}{2} = 6$, so the GCF is $4$? I mean, I chose $4$ arbitrarily, but I could have made just about any number $a$ work provided that $ab = 8$ and $ac = 6$, and I can just select $b$ and $c$ to satisfy those conditions.
I don't really understand how $\frac{1}{3}x$ is the GCF, since it is not an integer. I can't find much online at all about fractional GCFs, since most sites only reference them with regards to non-zero integers.

$4$ is not a facto for $6$ because to solve $4 \times k = 6$ we have $k =\frac 32$ and $\frac 32$ is not an integer.  To say $d$ is a factor of $w$ we don't need either $d$ nor $w$ to be an integer but we do need $k$ so that $dk =w$ we must have $k$ be an integer.  So $\frac 23$ is a common factor of $4$ and $6$ (but not the greatest common factor) because $\frac 23 \times 12=8; \frac 23\times 9=6$ and $12,9$ are integers.

What is the context, high school algebra or university (abstract) algebra?  Do they define "GCF"?

In this case the factor $\frac{1}{3}x$ is not representing an integer factor per se, but the term of $x$ that you would be able to extract to factorize the sum or difference of the two values. For example, $$\frac{5}{3}x^3 + \frac{4}{3} x = \frac{1}{3} x (5x^2+4)$$ This is the "Greatest Common Factor" that both the terms contain algebraically in common.
This is different than factorizing an integer, where a factor of an integer must be another integer.

"where a factor of an integer must be another integer." Must it?  It's a convention but there are some texts which will claim $\frac 34$ is a factor of $3$ because there is an integer $k$ (namely $4$ so that $\frac 34\times k = 3$.  According to some text $\sqrt 3$ is a factor of $\sqrt{12}$ not because either are integers but because $\sqrt 3\times k = \sqrt{12}$ for $k = 2\in \mathbb Z$.

I'm still a little bit lost though: why is $\frac{1}{3}x$ an acceptable GCF as opposed to pretty much any other value? As I mentioned (though with a different example previously), if non-integers are acceptable as factors, couldn't I arbitrarily pick a value $a$ to be the GCF as long as $ab = \frac{5}{3}x^3$ and $ac = \frac{4}{3}x$?

The gcd (or GCF) in a given ring is only defined up to multiplication by a unit. For example, if we are working with integers $\mathbb Z,$ then $\gcd(3, 7)$ is typically said to be $+1,$ but $-1$ is just as valid. Taking always the positive value for the gcd is a convention, which makes a lot of sense when both integers are positive, but what about $\gcd(-3, 7)$? Is it $1$ or $-1$?
In this case we seem working with the ring of polynomials with rational coefficients, $\mathbb Q[x].$ All non-zero rational numbers are units, so $\gcd(\frac53x^3, \frac43x)$ can be $\frac x3, x$ or $7x,$ so you are right.
Another interpretation is that $x$ stands for an integer, but is $\frac43x$ assumed to be an integer? This is not clear to me. Perhaps if you give the definition of GCF in your notes, the meaning can be clarified.

Unfortunately, the book has no actual definition written out. It just says to find the GCF of two or more numbers, list out all of the factors and take the highest factor shared between them, or use prime factorization and take the product of all of the shared prime factors.

@Luis Green: Unfortunately, the book ... --- People trying to answer your question will be greatly helped by giving some indication of the content level. Bill Dubuque asked (in a comment) whether this is school algebra or university abstract algebra, and you have not yet clarified this ambiguity in your question. Jon's answer appears to assume school algebra, although for me your comment there creates doubt. Keplerto's answer appears to assume university abstract algebra. One way to give the level is to simply not be so cryptic by saying "My textbook" and "the book", and simply cite it.

@DaveL.Renfro True, but the right answer should remain the same regardless of the level. The $\gcd$ of a polynomial with rational coefficients is only defined up to multiplication by a non-zero rational number.

@DaveL.Renfro I guess high school level? I graduated high school years back and eventually got to a college level of math, but it's been so many years since that happened and I've forgotten a lot of stuff, so I'm redoing the high school level stuff through upgrading. What's a bit confusing about the rational GCF though is I don't ever remember learning that was even a thing, even when I got to more advanced levels of math, so that was apparently something I was never taught in high school.

@Luis Green: I AGREE with your confusion over the problem and answer, which I originally didn't pay much attention to, as then I was mainly focused on the fact that you were getting school-level responses (factor so that only one non-integer number needs to be written) and university-level responses (rings and $\mathbb Q[x]).$ I suspect this may be some kind of study guide that was not very carefully written/edited, possibly by someone not particularly competent beyond being able to score well on a certain standardized test involving certain school-math topics.

the right answer should remain the same regardless of the level --- I suspect the author has a specific end result in mind (for numerical constants, minimally lump all non-integer'ness into the common factor) and wasn't paying attention to the meaning of GCF or CF (or perhaps doesn't even know their precise meanings). So I think the OP is correct to be confused, and I agree with you basically saying that the book's author technically seems to be allowing any (nonzero) rational multiple of $x$ to be a common factor.
